# R - add data frame to list

Tags: r

How can I add a data frame to a list in R? I am trying the following code.

First, I create a data frame from a csv file (any csv file will do)

```
> a <- read.csv(csvFile)
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
```

so, I have a data frame called "a". Now I create a list with one character item as shown below

```
> b <- list("hello world")
```

Now, I append my data frame "a" to the list b as shown below

```
> b[[length(b)+1]] <- a
> class(b)
[1] "list"
> length(b)
[1] 2
```

so far so good. List b now has 2 items (the character string "hello world" and the data frame a). Now the piece that puzzles me is the following code

```
> class(b[2])
[1] "list"
```

why is class(b[2]) showing up as a list instead of a data frame? I want to be able to add my data frame "a" to the list "b" without having a be converted implicitly into a list. Can anyone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: This is one of the best examples I've seen of confusion between `[` and `[[`. They do different things with lists.

Comment: Notice how you had to use `[[<-` to set the element?  That's a clue. ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is documented in `?"["` (or `?Extract`), in the "Recursive (list-like) objects" section (emphasis added):

> Indexing by ‘[’ is similar to atomic vectors and *selects a list* of
>   the specified element(s).
>
> Both ‘[[’ and ‘$’ *select a single element* of the list.

Since `b[2]` returns a list, you want to use `[[`, i.e. `b[[2]]`.